# Adding numbered appendices as section in documentclass report

Tags: sectioning, appendices, report

I'm writing a text using the **documentclass** `report` and I can't find a way to add appendices like this within the `article` class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\section*{Appendices}
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}
\end{document}
```

What I would like is:
- A main section (not a chapter, except if it's too complicated to do) named : Appendices without any numbering here
- subsection for every new appendices, with numbering (or letters)

Like this:

**Last chapter**
Last section
Last subsection

Appendices (as a section*)  `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}`
Appendix **1** (as a subsection)  `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Appendix 1}`

Appendix **2** (as a subsection)  `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Appendix 2}`

Appendix **3** (as a subsection)  `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Appendix 3}`

I would also like to refer to the appendices (with a `\label{stuff}`) in the main text regarding their number (or letter, I don't really care here).
Every try I've done ended with strange numbering begin either with a dot like this `.1` or with `.0.1`. Thanks.

Update:
This is almost working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\section*{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}
\end{document}
```

But placing the letter in front of the Appendix name and I can't place it as the end. It would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\section*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bfseries Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}% Restart subsection numbering

\subsection{First appendix}
\subsection{Second appendix}

\end{document}
```

If you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), more work needs to be done to accommodate for the referencing.

If you have more document content following the `\chapter` that contains your appendices, then you may have to restore the `\subsection` numbering. You can add

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```

before that content.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution, reducing the `\addcontentsline` stuff and `hyperref` subtleties consists in using  the `appendix` package and its `subappendices` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{foo}  
\lipsum[2]

\section*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\phantomsection
\begin{subappendices}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
\subsection{Fisrt app}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{second app}
\lipsum[4]
\end{subappendices}

\chapter{Foobar}
\section{bar2}
\subsection{foo2}  
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

and expected result like:
[image]

Comment: @Kola B. @Werner I have simplified and improve my former answer to show more clearly the power of the suggested package and the simplicity to make it working with ``hyperref``. `Moreover ``\renewcommand{\thesubsection}`` and ``\setcounter{subsection}{0}`` are inside a group, making unneeded to undo these changes.

Comment: If you /really/ want 'Appendix A' instead of 'A Some title' , you’ll loose some important role of a title, and enter into trouble in the table of contents.
 An alternative w’d be using ``\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}`` and  adding``\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{Appendix\ \thesubsection: #1}{0pt}{}`` just after ``\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}``. By this way you could append a meaning full title after 'Appendix A'.